# WPF Listbox wont trigger MouseUp or PreviewMouseUp

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a GUI with two listboxes:

```
<Label Content="Run My Accounts Mitarbeiter :" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
    <ListBox Name="ListBox1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}" AllowDrop="False" 
             PreviewMouseDown="ListBox_OnMouseDown" PreviewMouseUp="ListBox1_OnPreviewMouseUp">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image  Height="50" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding FullName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Label Content="Lieblingsmitarbeiter :" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" />
    <ListBox Name="ListBox2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding FavoriteEmployees}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="ListBox_Drop" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image  Height="50" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding FullName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

With this in the code behind:

```
private Boolean _dragFlag;
    private Point _point;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dragFlag = false;
        RMA_Roots.AppConfig.LoadAppConfiguration("EmployeeOverview");
        DataContext = new EmployeeViewModel();
    }


    private void ListBox_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _dragFlag = true;
        _point = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    }

    private void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dragFlag)
        {
            var parent = (ListBox)sender;
            var data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(EmployeeModel));
            parent.Items.Add(data);
            _dragFlag = false;
            _point = new Point(0, 0); 
        }
    }

    private void UIElement_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        if (_dragFlag)
        {
            if ((point.X + point.Y)+20 > (_point.X + _point.Y))
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(ListBox1, ListBox1.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UIElement_OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _dragFlag = false;
        _point = new Point(0,0);
    }
```

Now to my problem: When I start dragging an element from ListBox1 and then release it the drop wont be released UNTIL I move over ListBox2 where it will be added. I tried calling UIElement_OnMouseUp from my Grid and even from the Window and it just wont trigger.

Any Ideas on how to release the Item when the drop should not be completed? (Meaning the release is somewhere not over ListBox2)

Comment: Take a look to some examples http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43614/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF http://www.wpftutorial.net/draganddrop.html http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/07/12/drag-drop-in-wpf-explained-end-to-end.aspx

Comment: @Dimi ty, using gongsolutions now